# Identify C++ style comments with asm-mode in Emacs Lisp

Tags: assembly, emacs, comments, lisp

In Emacs, how do I tweak the lisp file(s) to identify C++ style comments in asm-mode? I have a compiler that deals with asm code but uses C++ style comments. I would like emacs identify C++ style commenting and show chunks of text wrapped in /* , */ as comments. The default comment start characters of asm-mode (?\;) can be ignored.

Comment: I just tried out asm-mode with GNU Emacs 23.1.1 and it seems to at least highlight both types of C++-style comments correctly. Could you give a concrete example what doesn't work for you?

Comment: It's not working for me in 24.3.1.  Specifically, `M-q` doesn't properly break long comments and doesn't properly "rebalance" long commends when edited.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Emacs 21?  If I'm reading the version history correctly, `//` style comments are supported starting with GNU Emacs 22.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `emacs-version` tells you what version you're running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :) .. I am actually using emacs 23.3. I need the // style comments working in the asm-mode. The lisp file I am using has a default comment-string identifier set to characters ?\; . I am not sure how to modify it to recognize the string pattern "//"