# Configure emacs assembly mode to handle C-style comments

Tags: gcc, assembly, emacs, configuration, comments

How do I configure GNU emacs 24.3.1 to "play nice" with assembly code to be compiled by the gnu assembler?

`asm-mode` assumes that the semi-colon is the only comment character. gas allows `#`, `//`, and `/* */`.

I figured out how to change the comment character to `#` using `(setq asm-comment-char ?\#)`; but, indenting and line breaking still don't work right. 
Specifically, if I type a long comment and press `M-q`, the lines break, but the additional lines are not prefixed by `#`. If I edit a comment and press `M-q`, the lines break, but the existing comment characters end up in the middle of lines.

Support for `//` and `/* */` would be nice, but I'll be happy if I can just get the `#` comments to re-balance when I edit them.

If there aren't any good solutions for emacs, can anybody suggest a better editor? (I did check out SASM, but it doesn't appear to "re-balance" comments. CLion only recently added syntax highlighting for assembly, and my University won't upgrade the image until the end of summer term.)

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Identify C++ style comments with asm-mode in Emacs Lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11660077/253056) and [How to add a comment style to an emacs mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41123697/253056)

Comment: The first one might be.  The second one appears to give an answer for one-character comment delimiters only.

Comment: The GNU Assembler itself uses `/**/` and `#` for comments. The `;` character is used to separate multiple assembly statements on the same line.

Comment: @RossRidge, I see what the GNU Assembler uses for comments.  How do I configure the Emacs asm-mode to use GNU's comments instead of ';'?